# When getting a Count in SQL, can I get a total count and a count of records where a column value is 1 also?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have SQL table represented by:

```
 public class Phrase
 {
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public string PhraseId { get; set; }
    public bool Hidden { get; set; }
 }
```

I understand I get a count of all rows like this:

```
select count(*) as Total from Phrase
```

But is it possible with SQL to also get a count of those rows where Hidden = 1 as well as the total count.  So my result would look like:

```
Count    HiddenCount
    
25          4
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is this:

```
select 
  count(*) Count,
  (select count(*) from Phrase where Hidden = 1) HiddenCount
from Phrase
```

Since there doesn't exist a Boolean data type in SQLite, I compared the value of column `Hidden` to `1`. You can change it to the value you use in the table, like:

```
select count(*) from Phrase where Hidden = 'True'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*) as cnt,
       sum(case when hidden = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as hiddencnt
from phrase;
```

Or:

```
select count(*) as cnt,
       sum(hidden) as hiddencnt
from phrase;
```

There is no native boolean type in SQLite, so assume that `hidden` is a number that only takes on the values of `0` and `1` for this answer.